# Substituição de strings em javascript

Tags: javascript, json, array, string

Possuo um input que recebe um código composto de 4 letras

```html
    <p>Localidade 
            <input type="text" id="localidade" oninput="MyFunction()">
            <span id="ca"></span>
    </p>
```

Pretendo desenvolver uma função que receba esse input e diga o nome do aeródromo, conforme arquivo json disponível em: https://pastebin.com/Y7gLPxR8

```js
    function MyFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("localidade").value;
    var y = String(x);
    z = y.length;
    if (z === 4) {
    document.getElementById("ca").innerHTML = "Aeródromo: " + x;
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("ca").innerHTML = "Aeródromo Inexistente:" + x;
    }
    }
```

Qual método posso utilizar para extrair dados desse arquivo e inserir o nome do aeródromo no span acima? Pensei em armazenar os dados em uma variável como vetor, mas iria ficar enorme...

Comment: Eu estava terminando a resposta e você apagou a pergunta!!!! Vou ter que fazer de novo!!!!

Comment: Desculpe-me, eu queria editar e cliquei em remover

Comment: To colocando a resposta. Não apague, e não vou fazer de novo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai ter que usar um AJAX para buscar o objeto dentro do JSON onde a chave `CÓDIGO OACI` seja igual ao valor digitado no input.

Para isso, crie um arquivo com a extensão `.json` (exemplo: `dados.json`) e insira nele todo o código do Pastebin que você informou.

Declare uma variável com escopo mais amplo que irá receber o JSON do AJAX (usei a variável `var json;`). Essa variável irá servir para armazenar o retorno do AJAX apenas 1 vez, ou seja, uma vez que essa variável receba o JSON, o AJAX não será mais disparado, evitando múltiplas requisições ao alterar o valor do input, pois todo o JSON já está na memória na variável `json`.

Depois você usa uma função (chamei de `busca()`) onde irá verificar, usando `.filter()`, se existe um objeto no JSON com chave `CÓDIGO OACI` igual ao código que foi digitado e mostrar o resultado no `span`.

Em vez de usar o atributo `oninput` para chamar a função `MyFunction()`, usei um *event listener*, porque assim você restringir o escopo dos objetos dentro da função do `DOMContentLoaded`.

Veja como fica o código:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Localidade 
   <input type="text" id="localidade">
   <span id="ca"></span>
</p>
```

**JS:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var json;
   document.getElementById("localidade").oninput = function(){
      var x = this.value;
      var z = x.length;
      if(z == 4 && json){
         busca(x);
      }else if(z == 4){
         var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
         ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
               json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
               busca(x);
            }
         }
         ajax.open("GET", "dados.json", true);
         ajax.send();
      }
   }

   function busca(cod){
      var res = json.filter(function(obj){
         return obj['CÓDIGO OACI'] == cod;
      });

      if(res.length){
         document.getElementById("ca").innerHTML = "Aeródromo: " + res[0].NOME;
      }else{
         document.getElementById("ca").innerHTML = "Aeródromo Inexistente: " + cod;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. A solução do autor anterior, apesar de que poderia ser adaptada, ainda exigia o carregamento do arquivo, o que eu não desejava. Vou ter que estudar mais sobre AJAX daqui em diante, pois haverão várias outros casos semelhantes.

Answer (score 2):

Para atender seus requisitos eu fiz umas modificação no html. Coloquei um `<input file>` para carregar o arquivo contendo as informações sobre os aeródromos para que possa ser carregado de um local arbitrário. Nos meus testes eu usei o caminho https://pastebin.com/raw/Y7gLPxR8 que é versão somente texto do conteúdo no pastebin. Também um botão de localizar.

Em JavaScript e adicionei a função `openFile()` que será chamada assim que um arquivo for selecionado no`<input file>`. Essa função lê o arquivo selecionado e converte JSON para objeto colocando o resultado na variável `aerodromos`;

Modifiquei a função `MyFunction()`, colocando uma variável consulta que detém o valor que será comparado com a chave `CÓDIGO OACI`.

Usei a método `find()` qe retorna o valor do primeiro elemento do `array` que satisfizer a função de teste provida. Caso contrario, `undefined` é retornado.

será chamada no evento `click` do botão localizar.

```js
var aerodromos;

function openFile(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    aerodromos = JSON.parse(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};



function MyFunction() {
  var consulta = document.getElementById("localidade").value;

  var encontrado = aerodromos.find((elemento) => {
    if (elemento["CÓDIGO OACI"] == consulta) return elemento;
  });

  if (encontrado) console.log(encontrado);
  else console.log(consulta + "não encontrado");


}
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<div id='output'>

  <p>Localidade
    <input type="text" id="localidade">
    <button onclick="MyFunction()">Localizar</button>
    <span id="ca"></span>
  </p>
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar aqui.

Comment: não sei se fui claro, mas deve selecionar o seu arquivo em formato bruto que é esse [https://pastebin.com/raw/Y7gLPxR8](https://pastebin.com/raw/Y7gLPxR8)

Comment: sem problemas, vou adaptar aqui

Comment: a propósito, o jquery é obrigatório?

Comment: Saiu sem querer. Não precisa de JQuery. Tinha feito de outra forma então optei pelo <input file> e JQuery acabo ficando.